# How many houses can I steal from?

Tags: python, algorithm

I had recently got the following question in an interview for a software position. As far as I can remember, it goes like : There are `n` houses at a stretch represented by an array A[1...n] containing their respective positions in sorted order.

For example, consider the array `A[] = {1,3,5,10}`. Each of the houses has a single gold coin, and you, being a thief, want to steal gold coins from `k` houses.

But there is a constraint: If I select `k` houses, then the difference in distance between any two of the selected houses must be more than `k`.
In the above example: If `k = 3`, then I can select houses with positions: `1,5,10`. If `k = 4`, I cannot select 4 houses based on the above constraint.

**I want to maximize k**.

In the above example, `k = 3` is the expected answer.

**Currently, I have a brute force naive algorithm where for every value of k starting from `1`, I check if that many number of house selections are possible. If possible, I increment `k`and do the same thing again.**

Can you help me solve it more efficiently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a transcript of a programming puzzle enunciation.  [a.k.a. "homework"]

Comment: I just want the algorithm, not code? Why are people downvoting?

Comment: You will get much more attention and help if you include your attempt to solve the problem and ask specific uestions about ways it can be improved

Comment: @User_Targaryen "Firstly, how do I tackle the problem? How can I efficiently solve the problem?". You're looking for an answer without showing what you tried. I didn't downvote, but this will naturally get downvoted. Why approach this problem and immediately seek outside help rather than attempt it and then ask for help when you get stuck? If you brute-force it, then it's off-topic here anyway because it's working code, so it should be on codereview.

Comment: I have already written about the brute force attempt. There's no use in giving you the brute force code as it is very understandable

Comment: See my (edited) post

Comment: My first instinct is to build a graph with edges equal to the difference between values, and then discard all edges with length <= `k`

Comment: @jsbueno: edited the question. Please don't close the question now

Comment: `k` cannot be larger than `sqrt(a[n] - a[1])` which might be a way to flip the logic of your brute force code (try successively smaller `k` values, quitting when you find one that works).

Comment: You sure this is python?  `A[] = {1,3,5,10}` looks like C to me.

Comment: @cdarke: The motive was to describe the problem in simple terms, not to focus if it is C syntax or Python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea:** Binary search the value of k.

Let the array be sorted

```
low=1
high=min(n,sqrt(a[n] - a[1]))
while(low<=high)
    mid = (low+high)/2
    if( mid is a valid answer)
        low=mid+1
    else
        high=mid-1

return high
```

Now to check if a given value of `mid` is a valid answer, you just use the greedy strategy:

Pick `1st` house, then keep choosing next house which is at least `mid` distance away from last chosen house and if at the end, the number of robbed house are more then or equal to `mid`, then a valid theft is possible otherwise not.

**Complexity: O(n log n)**

Comment: Why is not `high` just `len(n)` ?

Comment: @LukaRahne, you  mean ``n``, right? I changed it. It makes it even better.

Comment: The comma in your first line leads to a syntax error.  You should put the two declarations on different lines.  You can use a semicolon `;` for this, but it's really bad style

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, that is just a pseudo code, not any programming language.

Comment: @ee2: Will the greedy approach always work to check if `mid` is a valid solution?

Comment: @User_Targaryen, I think so, do you have any contradictions?